# Unity - obj model in Hololens shows up semi transparent

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, 3d-modelling

I've been working in Unity app with Hololens, and I've been using models downloaded from www.poly.google.com; no matter which model I choose, it shows up semi-transparent while running the app on the Hololens. This is how it looks at poly.google.com:

[image: Poly model]

And this is how it looks in the actual Unity app (another model that shows up the same as reference):

[image: Hololens model]

The way I import them is just to place the .obj model in a folder within the Unity project, and then use the "Extract materials" feature and assign them:

[image: Unity settings]

Is there anything I can do? is it expected? I'd like to show them with strong/original colors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you check the alpha of the material?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected with dark colours. Holograms don't erase the environment behind them. They add light on top of the background environment, and dark images don't add much light. You can see in your example image that the brighter parts of the holograms are more opaque than the dark parts.

This is discussed in the [Designing with Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/color-light-and-materials#designing-with-color) documentation:

> **Rendering dark colors** - Because of the nature of additive displays, dark colors appear transparent. A solid black object will appear no different from the real world. See Alpha channel below. To give the appearance of “black”, try a very dark grey RGB value such as 16,16,16.